# Create Cocoa application without NSMenu

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsmenu

I'd like to create an application that pops up dialogs based on system events. However, this application should not have an NSMenu associated with it.

What I've tried, none of which worked:

- Removing the NSMenu from the main storyboard but it doesn't allow me to delete it.
- Overriding NSApplication and setting menu to nil.
- Looking through Info.plist settings for a setting which allows my app to not have an NSMenu.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I presume you do not want to be able to see the app's name in the app menu title.

Comment: Nope, I would prefer not to.

Comment: I’ve been able to achieve this with an app that was created by my own editor, but not one made using Xcode.  In the info.plist I deleted the Executable file and Bundle Name fields after the app was constructed using Terminal (Clang) and my editor to create the bundle folder system.  With this technique there could be long term consequences that I am not aware of, but it can be done.

Comment: Correction: I used swiftc to create the app, not Clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question:

Setting "Application is agent (UIElement)" to YES in info.plist creates a window without creating a menu bar. This is the action I desired.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
  Save this file with name 'delegate_noMenu.swift'
  Create executable in Terminal: swiftc delegate_noMenu.swift -o nm
*/

import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
var window:NSWindow!
    
func buildWnd() {
    
let _wndW : CGFloat = 400
let _wndH : CGFloat = 300

 window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
 }

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}
}

let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let app = NSApplication.shared
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```

1. Save this file with name 'delegate_noMenu.swift'
2. Create an executable in Terminal by using: swiftc delegate_noMenu.swift -o nm
3. Manually build a folder system to create an app bundle:
   A. Create a folder called 'myApp'.
   B. Inside the top folder create a folder called ‘Contents’.
   C. Inside ‘Contents’ create two folders called ‘MacOS’ and ‘Resources’.
   D. Inside ‘Contents’ folder also add an info.plist file to match the image below.  Note that Executable file and Bundle name fields are left blank.
4. Add the executable file ’nm’ to the MacOS folder.
5. Rename the ‘myApp’ folder to ’nm.app’ which should change the icon and create a double clickable application.
6. Hopefully you will not see any menu items in the menu bar and have a functional app.  I used MacOS 10.14.6.

[image: app_noMenu]

Comment: Thanks for the really long writeup. One change I had to make: `import Cocoa`. Other than that, it completely made a window and ran it. However, running it in Big Sur it still changes the menu bar to include the application name. :( Oh well, you're a legend for posting all of that and I learned how to construct a .app folder from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested it on Big Sur and it runs ok on my system; no menu.  I have a screen shot but the censor committee won't let me post it.

Comment: I found the answer to my question: Setting "Application is agent" to YES in info.plist works.